# How to make the third parameter optional and adding some condition?

Tags: functions, function-construction, string-manipulation, parameters

I have a function as follows. The function has 3 parameters. Now I would like to make the third parameter `i` optional.
So you call call it like `myFunc[3, {1,2,3},1]` or `myFunc[3, {1,2,3}]`.

```
myFunc[n_Integer, list_?VectorQ, i_] := Module[{x, y},
  x = ToExpression["x" <> IntegerString[{i}]];
  y = ToExpression["y" <> IntegerString[{i}]];]
```

And I would like to add a condition that if there is no third parameter then only do the `ToExpression["x"]` and `ToExpression["y"]` below without joining the string `IntegerString[{i}]`:

```
 x = ToExpression["x"];
 y = ToExpression["y"];
```

Is there a neat way to do this?

The above is part of this funciton:
I tried the suggestion adding a function with two parameters but somehow it add an index `0` like `x0`, `y0` when you omit the third parameter.

```
Module[{M, idx, idxc, idx1, idx1c, Y, Yc, x, y, z},
  idx = Pick[Range[Length[list]], 
   UnitStep[list - 1] UnitStep[n - list], 1];
 M = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
 idx1 = list[[idx]];
 x = ToExpression["x" <> IntegerString[{i}]];
 y = ToExpression["y" <> IntegerString[{i}]];
 z = ToExpression["z"];
 Y = {{1/z, 0, -(1/z)}, {x, 1/y, -z - 1/y}, {-(1/z) - x, -(1/y), 
    1/z + z + 1/y}};
 Yc = {{1/z + y + 1/z, -(1/x) - y - 1/z}, {-(1/y) - z - (1/y), 
    1/x + y + 1/z}};
 If[Length[list] == 2, M[[idx1, idx1]] = Yc[[idx, idx]], 
  M[[idx1, idx1]] = Y[[idx, idx]]];
 M]
```

Comment: actually it's a small part of another function so I tried that but it added x0, y0. 
Let me added more detail about my function.

Comment: Does simply using `myFunc[n_Integer, list_?VectorQ, i___]` (i.e. `BlankNullSequence`) in the `i` variable works as needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define more than one interface for a function:

```
myFunc[n_Integer, list_?VectorQ, i_] := Module[{x, y},
  x = ToExpression["x" <> IntegerString[{i}]];
  y = ToExpression["y" <> IntegerString[{i}]];
  restoffunction[n, list, x, y]]

myFunc[n_Integer, list_?VectorQ] := Module[{x, y},
  x = ToExpression["x"];
  y = ToExpression["y"];
  restoffunction[n, list, x, y]]
```

Mathematica will then choose whichever interface fits the calling case. By using a common trunk `restoffunction`, code duplication is reduced.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is called [`Optional`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html). You can provide a default value, then inside your function check whether the default value is passed or not.

Read here [Optional and Default Arguments](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html#17673) for more information.

### Code

Here, the default value is `Missing["notFound"]`. `z` introduced to hold natural value for your operation (`""`) and if `i` is not the same as default, then `IntegerString` will be applied.

```
myFunc[n_Integer, list_?VectorQ, i_ : Missing["notFound"]] := 
 Module[{x, y, z = ""},
  If[! SameQ[i, Missing["notFound"]], z = IntegerString[{i}]];

   x = ToExpression["x" <> z];
   y = ToExpression["y" <> z];
]
```

Comment: `If[MissingQ[i], ...` would be simpler.

Comment: @Roman thanks for your feedback, Because solution's `Missing` has a custom message in order to be distinguishable from other `Missing`, I used `SameQ`.